# Array mapping to replace certain parts

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Alright I got a quite large array of data, now everything works perfectly besides 1 thing, I want to replace all dots inside the array with spaces (so for example "Element.ID.Name" will become "Element ID Name" now I have to use array_map for this, how could I achieve this? I tried

```
$filtered = array_map(array($this, 'clearDots'),$unfiltered); //calls the $this->clearDots
```

But I am not sure what code to put into the clearDots function at all..

```
private function clearDots($arr) {

        }
```

EDIT: I tried to do it with

```
str_replace("."," ",$variable);
```

But that just replaces all the text inside the array instead of replacing the dots

EDIT 2: 
This is the unflitered part of it

```
$unfiltered[] = $row['row_name'];
```

Thats how I push the stuff into that array

This is the full code

```
public function getAll() {
            $sql = $this->conn();

            $result = $sql->query("SELECT row_name FROM tab");

            if($result->num_rows >= 1) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $unfiltered[] = $row['row_name'];
                }
            }

            $filtered = array_map(array($this, 'clearDots'),$unfiltered);

            print json_encode($filtered);
        }

        private function clearDots($variable) {
            str_replace("."," ",$variable);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going wrong in your overall code, but what you tried is correct.

```
   $str = 'Element.ID.Name';
   echo str_replace(".", ' ', $str)."\n";
```

**EDIT**

if you fix the issue with not having a return in your callback, does is any of the problem alleviated?

```
    private function clearDots($variable) {

        // need to return something here
        return str_replace("."," ",$variable);
    }
```

Comment: Well the problem is, I am using array_push to push elements inside of it from some MySQL query. Now the thing is, I am only pushing field name into it. When I print it I get like "RowName.RowName.RowName" (of course those would be actual row names) but now I am trying to cut down those dots but I cant do it for some reason.

Comment: what is in $unfiltered and what are you hoping is in $filtered?

Comment: $unflitered is basically the raw part of it, just pushed array $unfiltered[] = $row['row_name']; and the $filtered should be same just without the semi column between the arrays, just with a space between each element.

Comment: die('<pre>'.print_r($unfiltered, 1)); and put the first element or two of output in your edited question pls.

Comment: "<pre>row 1" thats what I got from it. Its the correct output

Comment: I wanna just add up to that, I did get the correct output but still my problem exists. When I print out the entire array I get
row 1, row 2 etc. I dont want the commas. Well any signs besides the space

Comment: are you saying that the json encoded string has commas in it?

Comment: please try putting a return in the callback as i have added in the EDIT to the solution